# Implement requestHooks in cucumber/testCafe

Tags: automated-tests, e2e-testing, cucumberjs, web-testing, testcafe

When I want to add requestHooks (for example) to my test and fixture I basically don't know where to do it.

I am using this repo https://github.com/rquellh/testcafe-cucumber

Answer (score 4):

I find a solution. however, it is not stable: sometimes it throws an error: '[object DOMException]:\n    No stack trace available'. Maybe someone knows why?
The code ( after creat mock and logger object as in testCafe doc):

```
When('I log in as free user', async () => {
    await testController.addRequestHooks(mock)
    await testController.addRequestHooks(logger)
    await testController.wait(2000)
    await testController
        .click(selector)
        .typeText(selector,string, {replace : true})
        .typeText(selector,string, {replace: true})
        .click(selector);
});
```

UPDATE: now it works with wait() function, but maybe there is some more elegant answer for that?

Comment: solution is based on @mlosev answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56043709/9608547

Answer (score 2):

`testController` is available in `Given`, `When`, `Then` steps.
So, you can use the test controller standard methods: [addRequestHooks](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/intercepting-http-requests/attaching-hooks-to-tests-and-fixtures.html) and [removeRequestHooks](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/intercepting-http-requests/attaching-hooks-to-tests-and-fixtures.html).

I've modified the example from the https://github.com/rquellh/testcafe-cucumber repository to demonstrate the `RequestLogger` usage.

```js
const {Given, When, Then} = require('cucumber');
const Role = require('testcafe').Role;
const RequestLogger = require('testcafe').RequestLogger;
const githubPage = require('../support/pages/github-page');

const logger = new RequestLogger('https://github.com');

Given(/^I open the GitHub page$/, async function() {
    await testController.addRequestHooks(logger);
    await testController.navigateTo(githubPage.github.url());
});

...
Then(/^Logger should contain captured request information$/, async function() {
    await testController.expect(logger.contains(record => record.response.statusCode === 200)).ok();
});

...
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution (gherkin-testcafe: ^2.2.0):

The definition:

```
Feature: Check server names

Scenario Outline: Fetch pages
    Given there is the <url>
    When I check the response status
    Then the http <prameter> equals the <value>

    Examples:
        | url                    | prameter | value |
        | https://www.seznam.cz  | server   | nginx |
        | https://www.google.com | server   | gws   |
```

And the implementation:

```
const {Given, When, Then} = require('cucumber');
const {RequestLogger} = require('testcafe');

let logger;
Given(/there is the (.+)/, async (t, [url]) => {
    logger = RequestLogger(url, {
        logResponseHeaders: true,
    });
    await t.addRequestHooks(logger);
    await t.navigateTo(url);
});

When(/I check the response status/, async t => {
    await t.expect(logger.contains(record => record.response.statusCode === 200)).ok();
});

Then(/the http (.+) equals the (.+)/, async (t, [name, value]) => {
    await t.expect(logger.contains(record => record.response.headers.server === value)).ok();
});
```